# what is the difference between "I should have been" and "I should have to be"

Tags: meaning, tense

"I should have been" and "I should have to be"
I saw these two phrases in a book.
Is there any significant difference of meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

If you had been invited to Buckingham Palace for a reception and drunk a little too much, you might reflect afterwards that: "I should have been on my best behaviour".

On the other hand, if you were to receive such an invitation, you might reflect beforehand that: "I should have to be on my best behaviour".

That's to say: The first example refers to your (mis)behaviour in the past and the second reflects on how you should behave in the future.